# filling a 3 inch hole in a fire rated dry wall ceiling

Tags: patching-drywall

My sprinkler system in my condo was just decommissioned and 12 sprinkler heads will be reomoved.  As a result I will have 1 sprinkler head hole in the ceiling of each room in my condo (total of 12). My ceiling is fire rated with 5/8 inch drywall.  Can I use a round self adhesive vinyl plug to cover the whole if I stuff the hole with fire rated insulation. Or can you suggesdt another way to cover these holes vrs drywall and the mess it creates with spackling and sanding.  Would appreciate any help.

Ed

Comment: Out of curiosity, what would prompt the HOA to decommission a fire sprinkler system and not repair/replace it? I bought my condo specifically because it has fire sprinklers and I wouldn't be happy if they were removed.

Comment: I agree with Johnny. The last thing you want to do is remove a sprinkler system. That is the best fire protection you can get. .... Who contracted to decommission it? Was it not in the contract to patch the holes??

Comment: WOW.  What sort of demented fool would rip out the **best fire insurance money can buy**?  I'd move out and tell your friends to not ever get a condo there, because anyone who thinks ripping a functioning, Code-conformant fire sprinkler system out is a good idea is a **MORON**.  Or was this system doomed from the start by design errors or left to rot until its functionality could no longer be guaranteed?

Comment: Under the International Building Code since at least IBC 2003, removal of fire sprinklers from a residential occupancy would result in noncompliance. The exception is R3 until IBC 2009.

Answer (score 1):

The opening must be sealed in accordance with the listing of the rated ceiling/floor assembly. This will vary among the wide variety assemblies currently and previously listed. Unfortunately, there is no generic correct answer. A correct code compliant solution requires research and expertise atypical among homeowners, or plain dumb luck.

Answer (score -1):

It depends on what's over the ceiling.  If there's a boiler room, garage (not likely), or something that might cause a fire, I'd cut out and replace with type X.  If it's just an upstairs neighbor (unless he's a pyro), you'll be fine just plugging it.

Comment: Fire separation should be maintained in multi-unit housing.  1 Hr for single family dwellings like a duplex or apartment, 2 hour for places like condos where they are multi-unit but you own them.

Comment: Generally, floor/ceiling assemblies protect the upper occupant from the lower: because heat rises, fire tends to spread upwards rather than down. In addition, minimum fire ratings are dictated by several code sections and the most stringent applies.